# Offline webpage javascript sleep() or wait() function

Tags: javascript, html, css

I downloaded a website and I am going to work with offline. But I want it to be like as on the server. I mean the load time. While I am working on offline all items load very quickly. I want make it like on the [image](http://l1307.hizliresim.com/1c/z/qyrw5.png).

what can i add to html css javascript files. is there a sleep() or wait() function that i can use?

Comment: I don't even consider asking why in the world you would want that...

Comment: wait a minute what are we trying to do here...??do you want the sleep version in js if i have not mistaken your question

Comment: Why do you want to do that? We maybe can help you better when whe know the purpose behind this.

Comment: you could collect some url's and then automatically request them and save the response-time and define a dynamic average of the loading time of your favourite pages, you could pass this value to your client-side script, and make you whole page to display:none and after the dynamic-time-average delays, change the css, so have fun emulating the internet

Comment: there is a difference between online and offline.When your are online..request and response have interactivity.When you are offline..there is going to be no interactivity and the data wont come from a server,it would come from your local machine.

Comment: the original website has render problem. my boss asked me to work the webpage offline

Answer (score 0):

Do not do that, as it will require great effort with questionable result. If you want to measure performance, the only correct way is to do it on server.

Answer (score 0):

As javascript isn't multithreaded, you can't make the website to stop everything and wait but what you can do is, create a function for your own:

```
function sleep(delayTime) {
    var start = new Date().getTime();
    while (new Date().getTime() < start + delay){
        // do nothing
    }
}
```

Call this function wherever you want with a number representing the delay that you want.

Comment: I guess you mean Javascript, not Java.

Comment: Fabulous way to seize up the browser and run the CPU to 100%, probably leading to browser warnings that it wants to shut down the page.

Comment: He got what he asked, performance requirement was never mentioned in the question ;)